# ImagePartition with offset. Something wrong with the number of images

Tags: bugs, image-processing

I want to do ImagePartition with offset whose offset size is different with x(horizontal) and y(vertical).
Here I got Lena image from
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna#/media/File:Lenna_(test_image).png

```
lena=Import["/Downloads/Lenna_(test_image).png"]
Dimensions[ImageData[lena]]
```

The dimension was 512x512.

I want to part this image into small images, as in the size of horizontal = 80 pixels, verticle = 32pixels. The overlap between images are horizontal = 44 pixels and verticle = 16 pixels.

Since 80 + (80 - 44)x(13 - 1)= 512, 32 + (32 - 16)x(31 - 1)= 512, I think the number of small images become 13 (horizontal) x 31 (verticle). However, when I try

```
lenap = ImagePartition[lena, {80, 32}, {80 - 44, 32 - 16}]
Dimensions[lenap]
```

The number of image was 12(horzontal) x 31(verticle). I can't understand why the number of only horizontal images was strange, i.e. not 13... Also, the Image of

```
lenap[[1,-1]]
```

should be same as

```
ImageTake[lena,{1,32},{512-80+1,512}]
```

However these images are not same, maybe next pictures each other.

If someone who knows how to ImagePartition with offset properly, please help me!

Also, I want to confirm whether the whole image was used for the Image-partition, I want to reconstruct them into one image.
I found another question as
[Inverse ImagePartition with offset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163436/inverse-imagepartition-with-offset)
I wanted to do the similar thing, but I don't know which parameter I should change... below didn't work.

```
ImageAssemble[ArrayFlatten[{{Map[ImageTake[#, dh, dw] &, 
 Drop[part, -44, -16], {2}], 
Map[ImageTake[#, dh, {1, -1}] &, part[[;; -2, {-1}]], {2}]}, {Map[
 ImageTake[#, {1, -1}, dw] &, part[[{-1}, ;; -2]], {2}], 
part[[{-1}, {-1}]]}}]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug. If we compare it with `Partition` used on `ImageData` we see that indeed it must be `13x31` partitions. It can also be seen that the right part of image is missing after reassembling.

```
lena = Import[
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%\
29.png"]

Map[Image, 
  Partition[ImageData[lena], Reverse@{80, 32}, 
   Reverse@{80 - 44, 32 - 16}], {2}] // ImageAssemble

ImagePartition[lena, {80, 32}, {80 - 44, 32 - 16}] // ImageAssemble
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Your answer is very useful. I just believed the Mathematica code and have never doubted the bug...  Also, thanks again for telling me how to use ImageAssemble command properly.